# Blinking notification on website when changes are made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Ok so I have no code to show you guys since I have no idea how to even do the code for this but what my client wants is whenever changes or updates are made to a specific page on our website (we use Wordpress), that page's link in the navigational menu will blink.

So basically: page gets updated ==> link in menu blinks ==> link stops blinking when user clicks on page and views it.

There's lots of website change trackers out there but they only do email notifications.  My client doesn't want email notifications.  He wants the page link to blink in the menu.

Any idea on how to do this? Some sort of jquery or javascript code?

Comment: jQuery could achieve this for you. Check out some tutorials. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Your two options are a push or pull notification. Using push, you would implement web sockets so the server will push the update flag to the client that will allow the menu link to blink. Using pull, you would have to implement a timer method that periodically checks for updates. When an update is found, it no longer checks until the user clicks the link. There are many ways to implement, but that is the basic concept. Good luck.

Edit: just to clarify the pull method, that will be implemented client-side. A basic JavaScript timer is used and when triggered, you would perform an ajax call to your 'CheckForUpdates' method.

Comment: "There are many ways to implement" yea, thanks for letting me know that it's possible.  Now I have to find a code that actually makes it work.

Comment: If you need to implement something quick, use the pull method. What you can do is check for updates every X minutes and when the user clicks the link, reset the timer.